# What is the source of "Dharmecha Arthecha Kamecha Naathicharami" verse?

Tags: identification-request, marriage, shloka

Consider the following interpretation of a shloka, which is used during marriages

> In righteous, wealth and desires, one should follow other and should
> listen to one another

The shloka looks like **Dharmecha, Arthecha, Kamecha Naathicharami**.

From which text the above shloka has been taken?

Answer (score 5):

P. V. Kane in [*History of Dharma Shastras Vol. II Part I*](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.24397#page/n591/mode/1up) says the verse belongs to Āśvalāyana Gṛhya Pariśiṣṭa and Saṃskāra Kaustubha of Anantadeva which discuss the [Kanyādāna](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Kany%C4%81d%C4%81na) procedure in detail. Neither of these two texts seem to be available online.

> Kanyādāna: (the gift of the bride). Vide Pār. gṛ. I. 4, Mānava gṛ. I. 8. 6-9, Vārāha gṛ. 13. The **Āśv. gṛ. pariśiṣṭa** sets out the procedure about the kanyādāna which is the same even now. The **Saṃ. K.** p. 779 notes about half a dozen different methods of uttering the formula in kanyādāna. It is in this rite that the father of the girl says that the bride-groom should not prove false to the bride in dharma, artha and kāma and he responds with the words "**I shall not do so**" (**nāticarāmi**). This is done even now.

In footnotes he says the verse is quoted by Śabara in his [bhāṣya](https://archive.org/stream/ShabaraBhasyaTrByGanganathJha/Shabara%20Bhasya%20tr%20by%20Ganganath%20Jha%20Vol%202#page/n290/mode/1up) on Jamini's Pūrva Mīmāṁsā Sūtras and also by Medhātithi in his commentary on [Manusmṛti 9.101](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201468.html).

This is how Śabara uses the verse in his [bhāṣya](https://archive.org/stream/ShabaraBhasyaTrByGanganathJha/Shabara%20Bhasya%20tr%20by%20Ganganath%20Jha%20Vol%202#page/n290/mode/1up):

> ADHĀYA VI, PĀDA I
>
> ...
>
> ADHIKARAṆA (3): Men and Women are both entitled to the performance of
>   sacrifices.
>
> ...
>
> SŪTRA (14): Also because she is spoken of as connected with property.
>
> Bhāṣya:
>
> In fact, the woman is actually connected with property; as is clear
>   from the following words addressed in course of a dialogue at the time
>   of the marriage '***Dharme cha arthe cha kāme cha na aticharitavyā***' in
>   matters relating to religious performances, to property and to
>   pleasure, she should not be ignored'. – As for the argument that "the
>   wife and the rest have been declared (in the Smṛti) to be devoid of
>   property," – even though this absence of property has been declared in
>   the Smṛti, yet it is wrong; because it is contrary to the Veda. All
>   that the Smṛti therefore can be taken to mean is that the wife should
>   not be independent of her husband’s control; and this entirely for
>   the sake of peace and concord in the family.

Medhātithi in his [commentary](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201468.html) attributes the verse to Āpastamba but doesn't mention the work or the verse number. It's not found in [Āpastamba Dharmasūtra](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/apastamba-dharma-sutra) so it probably belongs to some other work of Āpastamba.

> Verse 9.101 [Summary of the Law Relating to Husband and Wife]
>
> > anyonyasyāvyabhicāro bhavedāmaraṇāntikaḥ | 
> >  
> >     eṣa dharmaḥ samāsena jñeyaḥ strīpuṃsayoḥ paraḥ || 101 ||
> >
> > ‘May mutual fidelity continue till death’,—this, in brief should be
> >     understood as the highest duty between husband and wife.—(101)
>
> Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):
>
> ‘Fidelity’—unstinted obedience in all actions. **Says Āpastamba: (a)
>   ‘The wife should not be neglected in matters relating to Duties,
>   Wealth and Pleasure’**;—(b) ‘The highest good of man consists in Duty,
>   Wealth and Pleasure, as it is declared that the whole fabric rests
>   upon these three factors.’
>
> ...